# Using Kafka topic for feeding seeds url to Storm Crawler

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, stormcrawler

We want to feed seed URLs from a Kafka topic to the StormCrawler based project.
Is there a need to change the Storm Crawler?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you'd need to change the topology a bit and add a KafkaSpout and connect it to the StatusUpdaterBolt; like [we do in the ES archetype with the FileSpout](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/es-crawler.flux#L22). The KafkaSpout will have to generate the same sort of output as the FileSpout for the *status* stream i.e. URL, metadata and status (with a value of discovered). If that's difficult, you can insert a bolt between the Kafka Spout and the statusupdater bolt to convert from strings to that output